# Email from new comments

Tags: comments

My blogs emails are working fine. I get all emails when new post and new register. But i dont recieve any emails when someone make a comment. Yes i cheked in admin settings. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).
- switching to the Twenty Eleven theme to rule out any theme-specific problems.
- [resetting the plugins folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) by FTP or PhpMyAdmin. Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems.
- re-uploading the wp-admin and wp-includes folders from a fresh download of WordPress.

Tip from a [thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-receiving-email-notification-of-new-comments-1) in WordPress forums.

Comment: i will try them right now, but re uploading the admin and includes folders will my settings and entrys gone?

Comment: No, all your settings are saved within the database, and the site specific content are in wp-content. Make a backup of your hole setup and upload all files except wp-config.php and the folder wp-content

Comment: unfortunately i tried all of them but no success

Comment: this plugin solved my problem. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comments-notifier/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip on comments notifier plugin